# Get a value of a column by using another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
          user     min     max
1         Tom        1       5
2         Sam        4       6
```

I got this dataframe, now I know the user is Sam and I wanna get its 'min' value. Like this (the user is unique):

```
df[Sam,'min'] = 4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First create index by column `userid` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.set_index('user')
print (df.index)
Index(['Tom', 'Sam'], dtype='object', name='user')

a = df.loc['Sam','min']
print (a)
4
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`, but because get `Series` is necessary select again:

```
a = df.loc[df['user'] == 'Sam','min'].values[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for accessing a scalar:

```
res = df.set_index('user').at['Sam', 'min']

print(res)
4
```